# In powermockito how to mock an object which has another mocked object as the parameter?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

I have these methods

```
    public File getFileDetails(File file){
                  FileDetailMaker fileDetailMaker = new FileDetailMaker(getFileNumber(File.getName()));
                  return fileDetailMaker;
        }
        
        public String getFileNumber(String fileName){
                 return  fileName.substring(0,fileName.indexOf(".")).substring(0,8);
        }
```

I am writing a test case for testing the getFileDetails() method. If I test it by creating a mock "File" object and sending the mock of "File" as argument, I am getting a null pointer exception because from the mock file, the substring cannot be obtained.

I have also mocked the FileDetailMaker object creation through

```
FileDetailMaker fileDetailMaker = Mockito.mock(FileDetailMaker.class);
            
PowerMockito.whenNew(FileDetailMaker.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(fileDetailMaker);
```

But I am still getting null pointer exception. So can you please help me with suggestions for this issue

Answer (score 0):

add this to your test case

```
PowerMockito.when(file.getName()).thenReturn("filenameisthis.extension");
```

where file is the mocked object of File type